# How to format file type to EUC-KR format Using FileSaver.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to save a file to EUC-KR format.
But after save, File format always UTF-8.

code:

```
var blob = new Blob([resultContent], {type: "text/plain;charset=euc-kr"});
saveAs(blob, fileName);
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: What is charset in the page itself? It's probably utf-8

Comment: Yes, default is utf-8

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: never been down that road before in browser but my guess is you will need a library to change the charset